# MKMapView crashing with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, annotations, mkmapview, exc-bad-access

I have the following line of code which activates the breakpoint

```
[mapView addAnnotations:grabinstance.itemArray];
```

This crashing randomly.  grabinstance.itemArray is fully populated always and is never changing at the time due to this bit of code only being called once the array is full.  This particular time this was confirmed as 323 items in the array.

NSZombieEnabled doesn't find anything at all either.

The backtrace is below and line 1154 is the line above.

```
#0  0x0126a372 in _insert ()
#1  0x0126a312 in _splitNode ()
#2  0x0126a3b7 in _insert ()
#3  0x011db253 in -[MKAnnotationContainerView addAnnotation:] ()
#4  0x011dfc2e in -[MKAnnotationContainerView addAnnotations:] ()
#5  0x011b0b30 in -[MKMapView addAnnotations:] ()
#6  0x00009257 in -[BigViewController plotItems] (self=0x614de90, _cmd=0x16464f) at /Users/zzzz/Documents/iPhone Projects/BigProject/Classes/BigViewController.m:1154
#7  0x005336c1 in _nsnote_callback ()
#8  0x01c18f99 in __CFXNotificationPost_old ()
#9  0x01b9833a in _CFXNotificationPostNotification ()
#10 0x00529266 in -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] ()
#11 0x00024071 in -[ItemGrabber parserDidEndDocument:] (self=0x617b540, _cmd=0x689aa3, parser=0xf6b4ab0) at /Users/zzzz/Documents/iPhone Projects/BigProject/Classes/ItemGrabber.m:267
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bug reported to Apple and as been acknowledged

Comment: Any updates on that bug? Is there an open radar link?

Answer (score 9):

You should check your annotations using **CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid()**:

```
if (CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(place.coordinate)) {
    [_mapView addAnnotation:place];
} else {
    NSLog(@"place %@ has invalid coordinates", place.name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. but I am still confused. Since my app was crashing 2nd time when I was adding Annotations with wrong co-oridinates & not 1st time. Any particular reason for that?

Comment: @SamyagShah Memory related bugs are often unpredictable like that.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem and i fixed it,The problem was with my locations,The objects in the array may not contain valid locations,They may be garbage values